# Multiple source of documents for llm knowledgebase

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, chatgpt-api, large-language-model

Want to have knowledgebase llm bot.

2 sources whole weblink and some pdfs.

Webdocs => Using langchain sitemaploader  got data in form of documents.

Pdf => Using langchain pypdf loader got data in form of documents.

Docs = webdocs + pdfdocs.

```
Faiss.fromdocuments(docs,openaiembeddings)
faiss.savelocally()
Qa=Retreivalqachain.fromdocuments(llm=chatopenai,)
```

**Problem:** Not getting upto the mark responses  or  seems that llm hallucinations sometimes.

**Query:** If I want to  train from two sources web link and pdf's, what's  the best procedure?

I am expecting a detail guidance and answer  so that I will get to know the mechanism better.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your posting the question uncompleted or you missed some basic steps, i am trying to give answer as per your inputs.

2 sources whole weblink and some pdfs.

1st case : you can store any kind of docks can be pdf or webdoc or anyother in your knowledge base, but how you storing its a important because those documents work as context for your llm,

you can used splitters for splitting and dump in Faiss

2nd case:

Qa=Retreivalqachain.fromdocuments(llm=chatopenai,) where is retrival and similarity search?

Query: If I want to train from two sources web link and pdf's, what's the best procedure?

3rd case: why you need to train u need to used RAG it will give a response from those document